# SavePoint not reverting changes after Post

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm trying to use a SavePoint to revert some data to a previous state, but it seems like the SavePoint doesn't work anymore after I post it.

```pascal
var mem := TFDMemTable.Create(Self);
with mem.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do
begin
   Name := 'name';
   DataType := ftString;
   Size := 50;
end;
mem.Open;
mem.Append;
mem.FieldByName('name').AsString := 'Test';
mem.Post;
ShowMessage(mem.FieldByName('name').AsString); // Prints Test
var SVPoint := mem.SavePoint;
mem.Edit;
mem.FieldByName('name').AsString := 'Test2';
mem.Post;
ShowMessage(mem.FieldByName('name').AsString); // Prints Test2
mem.SavePoint := SVPoint;
ShowMessage(mem.FieldByName('name').AsString); // Still prints Test2
```

Even if I add `mem.CachedUpdates := True` before opening the MemTable, the issue still persists.

Removing the `Post`s seem to solve the issue. But does that mean I can't post my data for a SavePoint to work? An explanation with how to use them properly would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`SavePoint` can be used only in `CachedUpdates` mode.

I don't see you are setting `CachedUpdates` to True.

After your first `Post`, you must call

```
mem.CommitUpdates;
```

Now your `SavePoint` will work.

See [Emd. DocWiki](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.SavePoint) for more information.

Comment: Even when adding `mem.CachedUpdates := True` before opening the MemTable the same issue still persists.

Comment: Are there any docs which say that the `Post` command clears the change log? In the Wiki you've linked they only talk about `CommitUpdates` doing so. The Wiki for the `Post` command also only talks about it writing a changed record to the change log, not clearing it.

Comment: You have to Commit the updates after the first `Post`.  Then the `SavePoint` will work.
You can only "toggle" between the Previous and Current Commit.
I misunderstood the docs about `Post` and what it did to the change log, so I have deleted what I wrote about that.
Hope that answer your issue.